# Qt WebEngine Password Manager - How To Detect When A Username / Password Is Used On A Website

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7, qtwebengine

I have built a browser in Python 3.7.2 using the PyQt5 framework. To create a password manager, how can I detect when a username and password has been entered and sent off, and what the username and password is, so that a popup can be prompted to save the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

The method `QWebView::url` can help you determine the current loaded website. You should have a local database with the stored passwords; so with the current domain, lookup any stored password in said database. (Ideally passwords will be encrypted with a password).

As for the HTMl insertion part, there are a couple of approaches you can take; I haven't done this in a while, but take a look a the following methods:

```
`QWebView::setHtml` 
`QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript`
`QWebFrame::documentElement()`

With a `QWebFrame` there are many helpful methods that you can use.
```

**UPDATE**: These above are deprecated but there are still ways to achieve this.

Note: You should have a robust *password-field-detection*.

Deciding when is an appropriate time to store a new password is a big more tricky, this is how it seems to work on commercial browsers:

- Detects a successful POST request that includes a `password`-type field (for this you need to monitor and inspect all HTTP requests that happen inside your browser.
- Find if there's a stored password for the domain. If there is, prompt users to update the password if it's a different password, otherwise prompt users to store a new password. `INSERT`/`UPDATE` the password into the database.

Comment: QWebView and QWebFrame are part of QtWebkit that is deprecated since Qt 5.6, currently QtWebEngine is used, so I presume that your general advice is adequate but the part you are pointing out is no longer valid. QtWebEngine is no longer handled by Qt Network(QNetworkAccessManager) but by the internal API + chromium so it is no longer possible to access requests using QNetworkRequest and QWebPage::setNetworkAccessManager(...) method

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your clarification. Is there a new way to access the network requests in the new versions?

Comment: maybe https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html, although I presume that Qtwebengine provides the required functionality, I have not yet been able to test it